# Laravel Login Issue (It is custom login)

Tags: php, laravel

I have made custom Login and Registration process with Laravel. Registration is working fine but Login is not working

**User Model (User.php)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
     ''
    ];


    public function post(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Blog');
    }
}
```

**My UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use \App\User;

use Auth;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|unique:users|email',
            'password'=>'required'

            ]);
        User::create($request->all());
        return redirect('/')->with('msg','Registration Successful');


    }

    public function login(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required'
            ]);

        if (Auth::attempt(array(
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password 
        ))){

            return redirect('/')->with('msg', 'Success');
        } else {
            return redirect('/login')->with('msg','Invalid Login');
        }




    }
}
```

Table:
[Table Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohmWd.png)
I tried all possible way to solve this error but I could not get any proper solution. If registration is working fine they why not login process?

Comment: What happens when you log in? there should be an error page displaying what is wrong.

Comment: It's giving error message: "Invalid Login"

Comment: did u check with tinker is the user exist ?

Comment: Are you saving password as Hashed in your table or not?

Comment: @YusufEkaSayogana: Yes

Answer (score 0):

you need to hashed your password so you can add this one line in your code and update your code near about the create Statement

```
$attributes->password = Hash::make($attributes->password);
$attributes->password = Hash::make($attributes->password);
User::create($attributes);
```

After this your Auth will be working